# Python: Create folders and recursively store data from array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, recursion, output

I need to recursively make directories and store my data output from multiply arrays in each directory.  For example, I currently have:

```
    output_lat=zip(name_lat[0], lat[0])
    output_a = zip(name_a[0], full[0], a_type[0])
    f=open('geo.out','w')
    for line in output_lat:
            f.write(" ".join(str(x) for x in line) + "\n")
    for line in output_a:
            f.write(" ".join(str(x) for x in line) + "\n")
```

This creates one output 'geo.out' with the format I would like.  But since 'name_lat', 'lat', 'name_a','full', and 'a_type' are all arrays (of the same length) i would like to first create a main folder, then subfolders named after each element with each geo.dat file printed in them.

For example, I would like the outputs stored in folders such as "~/main/geo##/geo##.dat" where ## is the index for the array.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have to add to your code the lines for creating those directories. On the other hand I don't think *"recursively"* describe what you are trying to do.

```
def output(output_a, output_lat, ouput_dir):

    # First create the hole directory structure.
    # -------------------------------------------
    ouput_path = os.path.join(ouput_dir, "geo{0}".format(index))
    # Check ouput directory existence.
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(ouput_dir, "geo{0}".format(index))):
        os.mkdir(ouput_path)

    for i in range(len(output_lat)):
        folder_name = os.path.join(ouput_path, "geo{0}".format(index))
        try:
            os.mkdir(folder_name)
        except OSError, e: 
            print("Error creating output dir: {0}".format(e))

    # Then create output files.
    # --------------------------------------------
    for index, (o_lat,o_a) in enumerate(zip(output_lat, output_a)):
        folder_name = os.path.join(ouput_path, "geo{0}".format(index))
        with open(os.path.join(folder_name, "geo{0}.dat".format(index)), "w+") as f:
            for line in o_lat:
                f.write(" ".join(str(x) for x in line) + "\n")
            for line in o_a:
                f.write(" ".join(str(x) for x in line) + "\n")
```

Comment: Sorry I am new perhaps I mean to say 'loop through'.  Anyhow, something strange seems to happen when I run this, i get the error:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pool.py", line 128, in pool
    with open(os.path.join(folder_name, "geo{0}.dat".format(index)), "w+") as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'initial_pool/geo2/geo0/geo0.dat'

Comment: I think it is creating an extra directory inside of each geo1, geo2, etc.  I just need one folder for each of these with the respective data file in it. For example 'initial_pool/geo1/geo1.dat"

Comment: Answer edited I hope this help. And If you figured it out with my help, plese upvote the answer. ;)